# How to access user data within service layer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, architecture

I am building an Asp.Net Core backend with the following layers:

1. Api layer
2. Data Access layer
3. Service layer

The service layer needs to filter results based on the user and its permissions. According to several articles, it is not a good idea to access the user via HttpContext inside the service layer because it should be independent of the presentation layer. The only alternative I am seeing is getting the current user inside the api controller and passing it to the service layer. Is this the only approach? I see it as quite tedious to always pass the user down to the service layer. I would appreciate some thoughts on this matter.

Answer (score 3):

You do indeed want to get the user data out in the api controller (the presentation layer) and pass it down into the service layer.  Not only will it keep your service independent of an HTTP context, it will also massively improve the testability of your code.

This will allow you to do things like use your service in an asynchronous context, or even push it out into a separate container/server.

Getting things out of HTTPContext is the modern-day equivalent of global variables.  Convenient?  Yes.  Toxic?  Yes!  Will ultimately make your application a big ball of mud?  Yes!  Sticking with architecture is how you keep your programs clean and boring.  Boring code is good code.  Solve hard problems, not hard code.

Comment: Thanks, that totally makes sense. However, I am kind of polluting all my service calls by passing an addititonal 2 parameters. Is there a cleaner way to do that?

Comment: What are the two parameters?  If you need user data, either user the user object, or create a new DTO object that has just the bits you need.  You can even have a utility function that extract the relevant bits out of HTTPContext and populates your specific DTO to simplify things.   

Don't see it as "pollution", the calls should reflect what is needed to actually complete the service call.  That's how you keep your code free of external context and generally scalable, supportable, and honest.  If you have a lot of parameters you can consider a parameter object to encapsulate them.